# How to handle multiple returns in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a return from a javascript function that looks like this:

```
return{"success": true, "message": "Password changed."};
```

How do i retrieve these when calling this funciton?

Comment: It's returning an object. You use the normal syntax for accessing properties of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning an Object, You can save it in a variable and then can access the object properties.

```
//function definition
function fun1(){
return{"success": true, "message": "Password changed."};
}

//function calling
var res1 = fun1();

//using the result returned by function call
if(res1.success)//true
{
    alert(res1.message);//"Password changed.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just an object. Just access the properties.

```
var obj = foo();
for(var key in obj)
    console.log(key, " = ", obj[key]);
```

You can also use just `obj.success` and `obj.message` to return the subsequent value.

Answer (score 0):

That's not "multiple returns"; that's returning an object with properties. So the calling code receives an object, and then uses its properties:

```
var a = theFunction();
console.log(a.success);
console.log(a.message);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function functionReturningObject(){
   return{"success": true, "message": "Password changed."};
}

//  use a temporary variable!!! this is a valid syntax but will execute twice
//     success = functionReturningObject().success
//     message = functionReturningObject().message
var map = functionReturningObject();

// when you know it contents you refer it directly
console.log(map.success)
console.log(map.message)

// when you do not know it contents, you can "explore" it
Object.keys(map).forEach(function(key){console.log(key);console.log(map[key]);})
```